# WITHOUT using Pandas, how do I analyze CSV data and only extract certain values from certain columns and rows of my CSV file?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that extracts the minimum and maximum MPG rating for cars. The car's information is stored in a CSV file. I believe I wrote the correct min/max functions, however, I wrote it as if I was looping through all of the rows/columns.

We are only supposed to include certain categories of cars for data extraction. The category of a car is the first column of CSV data, which has an index of [0]. The MPG rating I am looping through is in column 10, which has an index of [9].

We are not supposed to include the categories "van", "minivan" or "trucks" in our min/max MPG calculation. Is there a way to exclude based on these strings and loop through the remaining MPGs that are not excluded?

Lastly, once this is accomplished, I am supposed to write these results to a new file. Is there any way I can open the file being written, to check if my code works?

When I try to print the contents of the newly created file (based on user input), I get an error saying that file is not in the directory. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: We are not allowed to import Pandas.

**Current Code**:

```
print("Welcome to EPA Mileage Calculator")
yearChoice = int(input("What year would you like to view data for? (2008 or 2009): "))
while yearChoice != 2008 and yearChoice != 2009:
    print("Invalid input, please try again")
    yearChoice = int(input("What year would you like to view data for? (2008 or 2009): "))
saveResults = input("Enter the filename to to save results to: ")

if yearChoice == 2008:
    fileIn = open("epaVehicleData2008.csv", "r")
    fileIn.readline()
    minMPG, maxMPG = [], []
    for line in fileIn:
        line = line.strip()
        dataList = line.split(",")
        minMPG.append(line[9])
    print(min(minMPG))
    print(max(maxMPG))

if yearChoice == 2009:
    fileIn = open("epaVehicleData2009.csv", "r")
    fileIn.readline()
    minMPG, maxMPG = [], []
    for line in fileIn:
        line = line.strip()
        dataList = line.split(",")
        minMPG.append(line[9])
    print(min(minMPG))
    print(max(maxMPG))

fileIn = open(saveResults, "r")
for line in fileIn:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a bug in the two spots in your code like this:

```
line = line.strip()
dataList = line.split(",")
minMPG.append(line[9])
```

In the third line, you're getting the value `line[9]`. That's the character at index 9 in the line, not the value at index 9 of the list. Do `minMPG.append(dataList[9])` instead.

Next, you can check that the vehicle type is not in a specific group using an if statement. Something like

```
if dataList[9] not in ['van', 'truck', 'minivan']:
    minMPG.append(dataList[9])
```

For your last problem, you haven't saved anything in `saveResults` yet, or created the file, so it makes sense that you get an error when you try to read it. There are a lot of questions and answers on how to do that. Look to some of those, and ask a separate question if you can't get your code to work.